# Use file object of "with" more than 1 time

Tags: python-2.7, file-io, with-statement

I want to search a particular string in file and based on that i have to process file data.

I know how to do it by opening file 2 times.

Can this be done by opening file for only 1 time ?

code:

```
with open(path, "r") as _file:
    for line in _file:
        if "my_string" in line:
            flag = True
            break

with open(path, "r") as _file:
    for line in _file;
        if flag:
            process line
            ...
        else:
            process differently
            ...
```

I tried:

```
with open(path, "r") as _file:
    for line in _file:
        if "my_string" in line:
            flag = True
            break

    for line in _file;
        if flag:
            process line
            ...
        else:
            process differently
            ...
```

But here 2nd for loop starts from where 1st loop has left, it doesn't start from 1st line of file and that's why its not working here.

Comment: Why do you have to flag first? Why can't you process it directly in your if loop?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid because "my string" is between 1st and last line of file and also i have to process every line of file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewind the file position to the beginning before the second loop. You can do this with `_file.seek(0)`.

Comment: just want to know is there are other ways to do this ?

Comment: Why do you want something different?